# Does anyone know how to perform a horizontal xlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Does anyone know there is a cleaner way to write XLOOKUP formula to perform this lookup function.
The current formula looks like this, it becomes very long if there are many columns to lookup.

=xlookup(H2,$A$1:$A$9,$F$1:$F$9,xlookup(H2,$B$1:$B$9,$F$1:$F$9,xlookup(H2,$C$1:$C$9,$F$1:$F$9,xlookup(H2,$D$1:$D$9,$F$1:$F$9,"",0))))

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A horizontal lookup is not the issue here as the function can both lookup a value in a 1D horizontal *or* vertical range of cells. But you can't use `XLOOKUP()` to find a value in a **2D-array** like that, however; with those numeric case ID's and the use of Microsoft365, you could try:

```
=MAX(IF(A2:D6=H2,F2:F6))
```

Comment: Much cleaner than my solution. Avoiding INDEX even!

Answer (score 1):

You could use: `=INDEX($F$2:$F$9,SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$D$9=H2)*ROW($A$2:$D$9)))`
Note: This only works if there's only one match.

It checks if `$A$2:$D$9=H2` where TRUE = 1 and FALSE = 0. Than multiplies that with the row number of the cell in that range. All FALSE result in `0*row number =` 0 where TRUE results in `1*row number =` row number.

Answer (score 1):

You may also try-

```
=INDEX(F1:F9,MAX((A1:D9=H2)*(ROW(A1:D9))))
```

[image]